# JQuery Ajax PUT request not sending data to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax put request which is not sending data to server

```
handleUpdate(meal) {
console.log(meal)
var meals = this.state.meals;
$.ajax({
  url: `api/v2/meals/${meal.id}`,
  type: 'PUT',
  date: {name: meal.name, calories: meal.calories, meal_time: meal.meal_time, meal_date: meal.meal_date},
  headers: window.Auth.retrieveData('authHeaders'),
  success: (new_meal) => {
    this.setState({
      meals: meals.map(meal => meal.id === new_meal.id ? new_meal : meal)
    })
  },
  error: (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know it's not sending data to the server?  Have you looked at the network tab trace in the Chrome debugger to see what it is actually sending and to see what URL it is sending it to?  Also, the value of `this` will not be what you are expecting in the `success` handler unless you set the `context` value for the `$.ajax()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope, you had a `typo` below instead of `data`, you had `date`. Please look at the comment below

```
handleUpdate(meal) {
console.log(meal)
var meals = this.state.meals;
$.ajax({
  url: 'api/v2/meals/${meal.id}',
  type: 'PUT',
  // The below should be 'data'
  date: {name: meal.name, calories: meal.calories, meal_time: meal.meal_time, meal_date: meal.meal_date},
  headers: window.Auth.retrieveData('authHeaders'),
  success: (new_meal) => {
    this.setState({
      meals: meals.map(meal => meal.id === new_meal.id ? new_meal : meal)
    })
  },
  error: (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: This was it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I Have noticed that in the `url` you are using different single quotes, please make sure you use the correct single quotes, this sometimes happens.

Correct one should be `'api/v2/meals/${meal.id}'`

Also, make sure you follow a good example for the call to make sure other attributes are passed successfully.